# Implement the Auth Class to the php file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the details of the Logged in user's name by

`<?php echo Auth::user()->name; ?>`

Inside the php file.

The php file is under `views/layouts/profile.php`

I tried to include this inside the `profile.php` to make the `Auth` Class available.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
require '../../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Auth;
?>
```

The `autoload.php` file is loaded in properly. But still i am getting the error `Fatal error: Class 'Auth' not found` error in the `profile.php`.

**How can i make it available ?**

Answer (score 0):

put `use Auth` in your respective controller.See you dont need to add `use Auth` in your view file and there is no need to add `autolaod.php`.

Then use `<?php echo Auth::user()->name; ?>` in your `profile.php`.

Comment: I am regularly using the `Auth` in controller that is not the issue. Can you say me how can i use it in the raw `profile.php` file which is in the public folder.